# Rails: Specific Authenticated Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a database website. In order to doing ANY editing, a user needs to be logged in the site. A user can also be signed up. Currently, you can log in/out. If you want to sign up, a user has to be logged out and then can sign up.

I'd like to change this authentication where in order to access the sign up page, a certain user that is logged in can sign up a user. In other words, the sign up option won't show up unless an admin is logged in and the admin creates an account for a new user. How would I change my code to do that?

new.html.erb/confirmation

```
<h2>Resend confirmation instructions</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: confirmation_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, value: (resource.pending_reconfirmation? ? resource.unconfirmed_email : resource.email) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Resend confirmation instructions" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

new.html.erb/registration

```
<article class = "sign" >

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
 </article>
```

create user migration

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

edit.html.erb/registration

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %>        </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <br />
      <em><%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum</em>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

new.html.erb/sessions

```
<body>
    <div class = "head">
        <h1>Log In</h1>

       <div class = "image1" >
            <img src= "http://dx.deucex.com/i/logo.png" >
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<article class = "sign">

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

</article>
```

example piece of code where a user can only edit if signed in

```
...

<% if user_signed_in? %>
                   <%= button_to "New Vendor", new_vendor_path, :method => "get" %>
            <% end %>
            <%= button_to "Inventory", inventories_path, :method => "get" %>

            <%= form_tag vendors_path, :method => "get" do %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :contact_name => nil %>
        <% end %>
```

...

Answer (score 0):

The place to do this authentication is in the controller.   Have the controller action for both new and create registration check

```
if user_signed_in?
  #render page or do action
else
  #render 403 not permitted, or redirect to a default landing page.
end
```

Only doing the validation on the front end opens you up to a "clever" person just accessing the page via direct url, or submitting a create action directly to the server, without permission.